# In Stack Overflow for Teams can a team administrator/moderator "pin" key questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'm not sure if this is discussion or a feature request. In Stack Overflow for Teams I'm trying to "pin" key questions (as an admin/mod/owner) for my teams. Is this possible?

The reason I'm asking is that I had to seed it with a bunch of Q & A myself, since some of my team can be slow adopters and they need to see it first to really want to spend time on it. As a result, some questions are much more company-specific ones that I want them to see up top as examples, whereas some of the more recent ones were more "filler" technical Q&A's because that's what I had to fall back on and to flush out some of the tags we'll probably want to use.

Comment: so basically a featured questions box for teams?

Comment: This is not currently available - so I would assume you want a feature request on the tag.

Comment: @Tschallacka Yes that's pretty much the idea

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this should be implemented, but since it seems that SO will never add this (because they never care about users on Meta), we can use a (sort of) workaround solution:

1. Create a [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag (which should be admin-only, but [SO doesn't care enough to add that either](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384863/8384089))
2. Click "filter" on the homepage
3. For "tagged with", choose "the following tags" and enter [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured), then click "apply filter", like so:

[image: filter box with the options selected that I described in step 3]

Comment: It's a nice work-around. I don't use SO for Teams anymore, but their staff were responsive when I was trying it. If they seem not to care about your comments on Meta maybe try reaching out to your SO for Teams rep (in general, though on this particular question I think they later confirmed for me they didn't have this feature in queue).

Comment: @Hack-R The SO for teams rep can implement changes?

Comment: They just act as a liaison between you and SO. So, if you ask about a feature they can find out if it exists, if it's in development, or if not add it as a feature request that goes into their backlog for eventual development, etc.

Comment: @Hack-R I tried asking, and they closed it without explanation.

Comment: That's not good. Well, this workaround should help!