# Allow admins to set a tag to be admin-only in SO Teams

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, tags, stack-overflow-for-teams

Can we add a feature to make tags only addable and removable only by team admins in SO Teams, like the moderator only tags on meta sites?

Comment: Please don't edit your post with insignificant edits to bounce it to the main page. Feature requests are noted by the staff, and they will take care when they have time.

Answer (score 1):

This is on our roadmap! We're hoping to have this live sometime in November.